# using a dictionary with a file

Tags: python, function, dictionary

So I have a file with letters and numbers related to them in it which is written as a list like  this:

```
a    1
b    2 
c    3 
d    4
```

etc

I also have another file with the letters in it and a number of times to multiple them by so its like this:

```
a   3    b   5 
c   6    d   2
```

so basically it means that I want to get the value of A from the original file and multiply it by 3 and then get B from the other file and multiply it by 5 etc. 
I have made a dictionary of the original file but I don't know how to retrieve the number to use it to multiply. python essentially needs to go through the file being used to multipy and then see the A and get the value from the other file that corresponds to it and to then multiply it by 3.

```
d = {}
with open("numbers.txt") as numbers:
    for line in numbers:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        d[key] = int(val)
    print(d)
```

Comment: Load both files into a database and do it in SQL?

Comment: SQL seems like an overkill here

Comment: Do you have file with multipliers with this awkward format i.e. letter tabulator number tabulator letter tabulator number?

Comment: I'm not not sure what letter tabulator etc means. Sorry, I'm a complete beginner. My file pretty much looks like the above. there are about ten rows each with a letter number letter number arrangement and different combinations of the letters a - g and 1 -9. Hope that makes it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = {}
with open("numbers.txt") as numbers:
    for line in numbers:
        pairs = line.split()
        for i in range(0,len(pairs),2):
           d[pairs[i]] = int(pairs[i+1])
    print(d)
```